# Can we apply different timezones in the filename of files captured by Azure Event Hubs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-lake-gen2

Files captured by Azure Event Hubs are usually stored in the format of

```
{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}.avro
```

However, the placeholders available for the file name format are based on Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

If I am in a different timezone like UTC-8, the filename would be confusing(file captured at 04:00:00am on 2023-12-11 at UTC-8 would be named like

```
{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/2023/12/10/20/00/00.avro
```

Can I apply some functions in the name format so that I can capture the file in the format reflecting my own timezone? If not, what is the best practice to handle these data in Databricks?

What I can think of is to use ADF pipeline to capture and rename the data based on the timezone then save to another place, but hope there is some simple method.

Comment: Is UTC-8 in your case Pacific Time? That one has daylight saving time, so you will get overlap in names and it might overwrite files when switching from summer time to winter time.

Comment: @juunas yes it's Pacific Time in my case. I think it will always have 8 hour difference in the file name, it would be troublesome if I want to collect and save records for every single day

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/blob-storage-azure-data-lake-gen2-output)

> The timestamp of the created folder structure follows UTC and not local time.

You cannot alter it.

However, you can create a **JavaScript UDF** that converts **UTC** to the local time zone.

After converting, you can use that column in the **Path pattern** option while configuring the output.

Below is the code for the **JavaScript UDF**.

```js
function main(datetime) {
    const d = new Date(datetime);
    let tmp = d.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'});
    let tmp1 = tmp.split(",");
    let date = tmp1[0].split("/").reverse().join('/');
    let time = tmp1[1].split(':').join('/');
    return date.replace(' ','')+"/"+time.replace(' ','');
}
```

[image]

Next, to convert, add the statement below in your `select` statement in the query editor.

```sql
SELECT
    udf.convertTolocal(EventEnqueuedUtcTime) AS ConvertedTimestamp,
    ---your fields
    [1e7ed650-1d9e-50b9-0dcd-5db77c7add4c].[EventProcessedUtcTime],
    [1e7ed650-1d9e-50b9-0dcd-5db77c7add4c].[PartitionId],
    [1e7ed650-1d9e-50b9-0dcd-5db77c7add4c].[EventEnqueuedUtcTime]
INTO [output]
FROM [1e7ed650-1d9e-50b9-0dcd-5db77c7add4c]
```

Here, **`convertTolocal`** is my JavaScript UDF.

Then, you can set the path pattern as follows:

```
event_out/{ConvertedTimestamp}
```

ConvertedTimestamp is column name.

Output:

The output of the above column will be like below.

[image]

When added to the path pattern, it will create folders.

Below are the folders created in storage.

[image]

For more information about UDFs, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is this solution requires stream analytics as a pipeline to transform the input captured by eventhub first then save the result with altered timestamp to another ADLS and in similar folder format to the original one?

Comment: Currently how you are capturing data and writing it?

Comment: For now we are exploring reading the avro files captured by eventhubs with Databricks, either streaming or scheduled job based on the requirements, since we need the data to be displayed on frontend in like 30mins to1hr after receiving, not sure if there is any best practice on handling the eventhub data. Currently we are facing the timezone shifting issue when reading & processing data.